# On adding multicolumn to document, last page takes full page even if column has 2 or 3 lines?

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-writer

I am using PDFwriter to write document in C#. Which has a paragraph and then multicolumn section followed by next paragraph

```
MultiColumnText columns = new MultiColumnText();
columns.AddRegularColumns(20f, document.PageSize.Width - 20f, 4f, 2);
Paragraph ticketContent = new Paragraph(content, new Font(Font.NORMAL, 10f, Font.NORMAL));
columns.AddElement(ticketContent);              
document.Add(columns);
```

Now when I add next paragraph to document, it gets added at end of page or new page while I can see almost half empty page.

How to format such that last page column only takes required place.

Comment: You are using a version of iTextSharp that is *at least* 6 years old. The `MultiColumnText` object has been removed a long time ago. It is no longer supported and it should no longer be used, just like the version of iTextSharp you're currently working with.

Comment: can you please suggest, how to implement it otherwise. I can't find any reliable source. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't clear, so I can't answer it. I can only see that you're using a class that hasn't been used at iText Group for more than 6 years.

Comment: If you can make a very simple picture of what you want and what you are currently seeing it would help greatly.